# colors xml: "Attribute is missing the Android namespace prefix"

Tags: android, xml

This is my colors.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="white">#ffffff</color>
</resources>
```

This gives me the following error: Attribute is missing the Android namespace prefix
What can I change to make this error go away?

Comment: i hope your this file in res->values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try to add this...

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<color name="white">#FFFFFF</color>
</resources>
```

Comment: slight spelling error - missing the 's' `<resources .. `

Answer (score 0):

The error is in some other xml file where you have might have done `color = "@color/white"` instead of `android:color = "@color/white"`

I mean to say is that you have not used the prefix android in some other xml file